# Howto free memory allocated in a function

Tags: c++, xgboost

I'm using xgboost with C_API and I'm trying to find a source of memory leak in my code.
I have the following code:

// function definition in xgboost/c_api.cc

```
XGB_DLL int XGBoosterPredict(BoosterHandle handle, 
DMatrixHandle dmat, 
int option_mask, 
unsigned ntree_limit, 
xgboost::bst_ulong *len, 
const bst_float **out_result)
{
  std::vector<bst_float>& preds = XGBAPIThreadLocalStore::Get()-
  >ret_vec_float;
  API_BEGIN();
  Booster *bst = static_cast<Booster*>(handle);
  bst->LazyInit();
  bst->learner()->Predict(
      static_cast<std::shared_ptr<DMatrix>*>(dmat)->get(),
      (option_mask & 1) != 0,
      &preds, ntree_limit,
      (option_mask & 2) != 0,
      (option_mask & 4) != 0);
  *out_result = dmlc::BeginPtr(preds);
  *len = static_cast<xgboost::bst_ulong>(preds.size());
  API_END();
}
```

// In the main functions that is calling XGBoosterPredict
// h_booster, h_test are defined correctly

```
const float *f;
XGBoosterPredict(h_booster, h_test, 0, 0, &out_len, &f);
```

//

Inside XGBoosterPredict the following is assigned to the pointer:

```
std::vector<bst_float>& preds = XGBAPIThreadLocalStore::Get()->ret_vec_float;
*out_result = dmlc::BeginPtr(preds);
```

Question: What is a right way to free memory allocated for f ??

Answer (score 0):

You're not meant to free `*f`.

`dmlc::BeginPtr(preds)` safely returns the address of `preds`, which represents statically-allocated memory (that's what `XGBAPIThreadLocalStore::Get()` does), so you don't need to worry about freeing memory here.

It looks like your memory leak is caused by some other issue.